# How to add js file to custome module in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, module, javascript

I have some script code in my phtml like below.

> path - Company/Module/view/templates/test.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var color = null;
var framecolor = null;

function Calculation(){

//frame color calculation
color = document.getElementById('color').value;

    if(color=="White"){
        framecolor = (0 * circumeference);
        document.getElementById("framecolor").innerHTML = "FrameColor Price : " + framecolor;
    }
    else if(color=="Red"){
        framecolor = (4 * circumeference);
        document.getElementById("framecolor").innerHTML = "FrameColor Price : " + framecolor;
    }
    else if(color=="Green"){
        framecolor = (8 * circumeference);
        document.getElementById("framecolor").innerHTML = "FrameColor Price : " + framecolor;
    }
    else if(color=="Black"){
        framecolor = (12 * circumeference);
        document.getElementById("framecolor").innerHTML = "FrameColor Price : " + framecolor;
    }
    else if(color=="Wood limitation"){
        framecolor = (18 * circumeference);
        document.getElementById("framecolor").innerHTML = "FrameColor Price : " + framecolor;
    }
}
```

How can I add this script code as a js file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1 :** Move your file in `Company/Module/view/frontend/web/js/some_name.js`

**Step 2 :** Add your file in layout like `module_index_index.xml`

```
<head>
    <script src="Companu_Module::js/some_name.js"/>
</head>
```

**Step 3 :** Execute Command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Then give permission if required.

Now , refresh your page.

Comment: Why is this better than the other solutions?

Comment: By add in layout, when you merge minify js then, this js file merge with main js file. So, it's better standard and it's call in this page only so.

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1**: Move your JS code into `Company/Module/view/frontend/web/js/test.js`

**Step 2**: Create `requirejs-config.js` file in Company/Module/view/frontend/ with content:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            testjs:     'Company_Module/js/test'
        }
    }
};
```

**Step 3:** add this at the end of your template file where you want this JS to be called

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Company_Module/js/test": {}
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Move your JS code into `Company/Module/view/frontend/web/js/some_name.js`

**Step 2:** Create requirejs-config.js in `Company/Module/view/frontend/` with content like this

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "someName":           "js/some_name"
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Inside your template file, where you put your previous javascript code, add this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['someName'], function () {});
</script>
```

**Step 4:** You can use `Calculation()` from now inside any template of the current module. (Obviously you need to require() it first in template).

Comment: I tried as u said but not working

Comment: You need to clear static content or switched to developer on your local.

Comment: im in developer mode but its not working I cant even display a simple alert

Comment: @ToanNguyen, getting require is not defined error in console

Answer (score 0):

you can used jquery like this

```
$m=jQuery.noConflict();

$m('#color').val();
```

Comment: can u explain more im new to these stuff